# React.js: How to get and show current user when logged in?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

In my **React app** I am working in **user login**. My goal is to show current **user's username** when the **user** is **logged in**.
 I'm fetching the **user data** in **redux actions** and, as I followed some tutorials, I need to get jwt token coming from backend in fetch function. In login Fetch function I'm trying to get and save the **token**(see fetching function), but it shows **undefined** in devtools/localStorage. 
This is how InitialState updates in LoginSuccess in Reducers.

```
state 
{user: {…}, loading: true, error: "", isAuthenticated: false, users: {…}}
error: ""
isAuthenticated: false
loading: true
user: {user: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRVc…xMTB9.hNsYTKGYIFRsPXw66AhB1o0EXyyfgfRTzOFzqBfjaTg"}
users: {user: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dnZWRVc…xMTB9.hNsYTKGYIFRsPXw66AhB1o0EXyyfgfRTzOFzqBfjaTg"}
__proto__: Object
```

I don't know how to get access to the current **logged in user data**: **username** or **firstName** for instanse. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Actions

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'

import {
  FETCH_USER_REQUEST,
  UserActions,
  User,
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_LOGIN_FAILURE,
  LOGOUT,
} from '../../types/UserType'

export const fetchUserRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USER_REQUEST,
  }
}

export const fetchLoginFailure = (error: UserActions) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_LOGIN_FAILURE,
    payload: error,
  }
}

export function logout(): UserActions {
  return {
    type: LOGOUT,
  }
}

export function loginSuccess(user: User): UserActions {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      user,
    },
  }
}

export const login = ({ email, password }: any) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchUserRequest())
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/logIn', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const users = response.data
          dispatch(loginSuccess(users))
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', users.auth_token)
          console.log('users', users) // undefined
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchLoginFailure(error.message))
      })
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
import {
  LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
  UserActions,
  UserState,
  LOGOUT,
} from '../../types/UserType'

const initialState: UserState = {
  user: {},
  loading: false,
  error: '',
  isAuthenticated: false,
}

const UserReducer = (state = initialState, action: UserActions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
    console.log('state', state) // initialState update see above
    return {
      ...state,
      loading: false,
      user: action.payload,
      users: action.payload,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      error: '',
    }
  case LOGOUT:
    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: null,
      users: [],
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}

export default UserReducer
```

And I assume I am going to show user userName or firstName in **logout** component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Icon, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import { logout } from '../../../redux/User/UserActions'
import { AppState } from '../../../types'

function Logout() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const user = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user.user)
    console.log('user', user)

    const logoutOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(logout())
        localStorage.clear()
    }
    return (
        <Button
            color="black"
            as={Link}
            to="Login"
            name="logout"
            onClick={logoutOnClick}
        >
            <Icon name="sign out"> </Icon>Logout
        </Button>
    )
}

export default Logout
```

Comment: First of all, did you test your API on place like Postman and does it work there?

Comment: HI @ kunquan, thanks for answer. First, I tried it in Postman, it worked fine. 
But if you want, I can provide any snipped of code you, that could help to solve this. I couldn't solve this for quite a long time

Answer (score 2):

You save your logged-in data to localStorage like auth_token you did and clear in logout function.

```
 axios
      .post('http://localhost:8000/logIn', {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const users = response.data
          dispatch(loginSuccess(users))
          localStorage.setItem('jwt', users.auth_token)
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(users))
          console.log('users', users) // undefined
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchLoginFailure(error.message))
      })
```

and access inside your logout component or wherever you need that

```
let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

and clear it inside logout function

```
const logoutOnClick = () => {
        dispatch(logout())
        localStorage.clear() // already clearing
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Vahid Akhtar thanks for the answer. 
When I tried  'let userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
' in 'Logout'  component, it throws an error like this 
'Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  '
Could you help, please, with that , I can't figure out how to solve.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Greg you can check like `if(!localStorage.getItem('user')){ // Code here }` to ensure that it's not null

Comment: Hey @Vahid Akhtar thanks for the response. I tried this, but didn't help. It throws the same error

Comment: `const AUTH_TOKEN: string=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`persist:${APP_STATE_NAME}`)!)?.token!` If you are using typescript